# understanding ps -ef output

Tags: ps

```
root@he:/home/he# ps -ef|grep init
root         1     0  0 08:40 ?        00:00:02 /sbin/init
root      3557  3545  0 10:09 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto init
```

What are various columns representing here?

Comment: just to note, since by your rep I assume you're new: you've been downvoted into oblivion because this question shows zero research effort. you could probably find this just by Googling; my cursory search for "ps columns" showed an entire page of links that look promising. we're happy to help you, but we're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: as a side note, you could better do that with `pgrep`.

Answer (score 4):

Your `grep` filters out the relevant part of the output of `ps`:

```
ps -ef | head ; ps -ef | fgrep init
```

should get you:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Feb13 ?        00:00:01 /sbin/init
```

have a look at `man ps` for an explanation of the column contents.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't add a comment to Anthon's answer. so adding below. 
Perhaps adding a -1 param to head command would be most suited in all *x platforms

```
ps -ef | head -1; ps -ef | fgrep init
              ^^^
```